# Swagger 3 documenting Map using annotations

Tags: scala, dictionary, annotations, swagger-3.0

I have a model for response in Scala:

```
case class ModelDto(
...
map: Map[UUID, AnotherDto]
...
)
```

**How can I document this using annotations** @Schema or @ArraySchema or smth like that?

Have no yml file and all fields describing using only Schema|ArraySchema like this:

```
case class ModelDto(
@Schema(description = "field description", required = true, `type` = "string", example = "field example")
  field: String
)
```

Comment: What is the issue? What is preventing you to document it? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to do something like this:

```
case class ModelDto(
...
@Schema(implementation=classOf[YourTypeMap])
map: Map[UUID, AnotherDto]
...
)

class YourTypeMap extends java.util.HashMap[UUID, AnotherDto] {}
```